# Eventos clicks dentro do next.js

Tags: events, next.js

I'm developing an application with next but I came across a problem: "onClick is not being called no matter what I do, I've already used it as an anonymous function within the component, I've already used an external function but nothing works, please tell me something if you find a solution, here is the code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Heart, List, MagnifyingGlass, Truck } from 'phosphor-react'
import { Section } from '..'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { HeaderListLinkList } from './HeaderListLinkList'
import { UserLoggedHeader } from './UserLoggedHeader'
import Image from 'next/image'
import { BsFacebook, BsLinkedin } from 'react-icons/bs'


const links = [
  {
    'url':'/pc-gamer',
    'link':'PC Gamer'
  },
  {
    'url':'/home-office',
    'link':'Home Office'
  },
  {
    'url':'/workstation',
    'link':'Workstation'
  },
  {
    'url':'/periferics',
    'link':'Periferics'
  },
  {
    'url':'/hardware',
    'link':'Hardware'
  }
]

const Header:React.FC = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(false)

  function handleClick() {
    alert("Click!")
  }

  return (
    <header className="w-[100%] bg-black sticky top-[-60px] z-[5000] header-box-shadow">
      <div className="w-[100%] h-[60px] flex items-center justify-center bg-[#FE093C]">
        <Image 
          src="/assets/img/header.webp" 
          className='object-cover'
          height={1000}
          width={1000}
          alt='logo'
        />
      </div>
      <Section.Content>
        <div className="h-[100px] flex justify-between items-center gap-12 m-auto">
          <section className='flex gap-10'>
            <Link href='/'>
              <Image 
                src="/assets/img/logo1.png" 
                alt="logo" 
                className='pb-1'
                width={170}
                height={170}
              />
            </Link>



            <div className="flex-1 flex justify-center items-center gap-3">
              <div className="flex items-center gap-6 relative border">
                <ul className="flex justify-center items-end pt-1 gap-3 relative items-link-list">
                  {links.map((item, i) => (
                    <HeaderListLinkList link={item} key={i}/>
                  ))}                  
                </ul>
                <div className='flex justify-normal items-center gap-2'>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="O que você procura..."
                    className="w-[185px]"
                  />
                    <button className='p-[.4rem]'>
                      <i className='text-[#FFF] text-[1.5rem] font-extrabold'>
                        <MagnifyingGlass />
                      </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              {status ? (
                <UserLoggedHeader />
              ):(
                <div className='ml-auto flex justify-end items-center gap-3 flex-1 border'>
                  <button
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    className='z-[10000] flex justify-center gap-2 items-center bg-slate-800/50 py-2 pl-2 pr-4 rounded-md'>
                    <i className='text-[1.5rem]'>
                      <BsLinkedin />
                    </i>
                    Linkedin
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    className='z-[10000] flex justify-center items-center bg-slate-800/50 text-white rounded-md pr-2'>
                    <Image 
                      src='/assets/img/google-logo.png'
                      alt='google-logo'
                      height={40}
                      width={40}
                    />
                    Entre com Google
                  </button>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </Section.Content>
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: could you provide the entire component code please. Is this a functional component or a class component?

Comment: It's a function component, I will send the rest of the code

Comment: Now can you help me? every time that i call some function inside the button not work

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the console? it works on my computer when I removed a bunch of the other components you are using.

Comment: It shows absolutely no errors, it just doesn't work, I'm using Next@14 by the way, Which components did you remove exactly?

Comment: This isn't the first time this error has occurred to me.

Comment: I added an answer with what worked for me, could you try it please

Comment: Ok, i´ll try it

Answer (score 0):

I'm calling from inside the document

```
import { BuyWith, Footer, Header } from '@/components/_ui'
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'


export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="pt-br">
      <body>
        <Head />
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```